# Unity/C#, Creating references to existing class instances (GC)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, garbage-collection

So I'm making a small mobile game and trying to structure everything best as I can... but there be questions.

Assume you have a collection of weapons in an array, how bad would it be to create a reference (activeWeapon) to a weapon in the collection and use that rather than accessing the collection directly in the array?

E.g.

```
public Weapon activeWeapon; // Accessing this, and re-assigning from collection when changing weapon.
public Weapon[] weaponCollection;
```

I'm assuming "activeWeapon" is just an address pointer right? So assigning it to another weapon in the collection should not give too much garbage?

Or am I being a bad man?

Comment: That's just a pointer to an object

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, as you said it just points to the GameObject. Using the single reference and the reference from the array will give the same result and the reference will be updated in both variables

Comment: Variables of a reference type are not "garbage", they are just variables that refer to objects. Objects (typed as a ref type) become "garbage" when there are no longer any references to them. In most programs, you don't usually need to think too hard about garbage and GC issues. There are two key times to worry. 1) when you spin out a lot of objects that quickly become garbage (string concatenation in a loop is good at this), and 2) when you inadvertently hold a reference to an object for much longer than you should, preventing it from becoming garbage. Generally, things mostly "*just work*"

Comment: I see, that clears up a lot. Thanks for the quick responses =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your you defined a `Weapon` as a Class in C# (i.e. not a Struct) it is completely OK to do it the way you described. `activeWeapon` is just a reference, so you can change it as many times as you want and it will not cause any additional garbage as you will still have a single instance of that `Weapon` even if you reference it twice from two different places.

You can read more about reference types here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I completely forgot that the actual pointer resides on the stack and only references on the heap. Thanks again.